# how to fetch a file in the same directory in javascript since firefox 68

Tags: javascript, fetch, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using vanilla js to load some HTML parts of a static web page, it's for the header and the footer so I don't have to rewrite them on every new pages I create. I write them in a text file and add them to the page with a fetch :

folder structure :

```
..
index.html
elements/
    header.html
scripts/
    scripts.js
```

content of ./scripts/scripts.js

```
insert_html("./elements/header.html", ".header");

function insert_html(text_from, insert_to) {
    fetch(text_from)
        .then(response => {
            return response.text()
        })
        .then(data => {
            document.querySelector(insert_to).innerHTML = data;
        });
}
```

It used to work pretty well until recently, it's now broken on local, but it still works online, I think because `fetch()` replace the relative path by the `https://example.com/file` url of the website when it's online, but it replaces it by the `file:///path/to/the/file` url in local

Indeed, the reason it broke is because of a security fix that came with Firefox 68, here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp about cross origin requests, because allowing to fetch another file in the same directory was a pbm, so now you can't use a `file:///` path anymore

How can I make it work locally ? I don't know how to use a `https://` path for a local use ?

Comment: as mentioned in the **documentation you linked to** .... change the `privacy.file_unique_origin` preference - though local http (doesn't have to be https) server is the better option for *developing* - and there's so many to choose from

Comment: Have you tried using http://localhost/? You would need a web server running locally on your computer but that's doable.

Comment: If you happen to have python installed, you can host your files locally by just running `python -m http.server` in the directory you want to host

Comment: ok, running a server is the only option ? it feels like i'll be using a heavy process for just executing a little html + js ? @Bravo, i'm sorry i don't understand all of your answer, because of my poor level in english, you say that when i'm in developing phase the better option is to run a local server rather than just launching code with a browser directly from file, `> firefox index.html`, eventhoufh i don't use backend like php or node.js or databases ? and then you add **"there is so many to choose from"**, so many what ? so many ways of running a local server ?

Comment: so many http server solutions to choose from ... and ... I didn't say "server is the only option" ... I pointed out that the documentation you linked to (and obviously didn't read) has a workaround ... that is, *change the `privacy.file_unique_origin` preference* - that's how you make firefox 68+ work like 67

Comment: @Bravo  I did read the documentation, but the proposed solution : `This new behavior is enabled by default using the privacy.file_unique_origin preference` is just a workaround indeed, i was hoping something that doesn't break security and don't requires a server, because it feels weird for such a simple web page. but thanks